# How can I use Amharic font in Qt user interface?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I am working on an academic project, as part of which I am developing an application that will run on Raspberry Pi (installed with Raspbian Jessy). I am using Qt to create UI for the application that will run on the Raspberry Pi.

I am trying to internationalize the application mentioned above. As part of the localization, Amharic is one of the languages I am working on. Unfortunately, Amharic is not fully supported in the internationalization process by Qt based on the following links below:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/internationalization.html
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html

Considering this limitation how can I manage to find an alternative solution to use the Keyman AbysinicalSIL-R.ttf font in my application running on Raspberry pi?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Those pages don't mention Amharic as not-fully-supported.

Comment: You should be able to use any font the underlying font engine supports. Did you try it?

Comment: Thanks Murphy, I tried it and it worked. I had to copy the Abysinica*.ttf into a directory where qt libraries are stored on Raspberry pi.

Comment: @hyde, the issue was problem rendering Amharic font specifically Abysinica*.ttf on Raspberry Pi. However, it is resolved now. Thanks